# PhpSpreadsheet: Permissions | ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I would like to offer an Excel-File for download with PhpSpreadsheet

Here is my code:

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="hello_world.xlsx"');
    $writer->save("php://output");
```

I get the following error message:

```
    PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /Users/sg/GitWorkingCopies/xxx1/xxx2/library/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php on line 374
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file php://output.' in /Users/sg/GitWorkingCopies/xxx1/xxx2/library/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php:375
```

The [dokumentation of PHPSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/) says:

> \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx uses temporary storage when writing to php://output. By default, temporary files are stored in the script's working directory. When there is no access, it falls back to the operating system's temporary files location.

The upload_tmp_dir is: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/`

Which folder permissons do I have to check? 
Or what does cause the problem?

Comment: If the problem was solved, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem, or you can provide and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

General rules for a directory in PHP to write to it:

***It must exist***,

***It is writable by PHP process***,

***It is allowed by [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) php.ini directive.***

Therefore, set some file path as argument in the `$writer->save()` method and check that these 3 rules are met.

If you want to use only `php://output` or `php://stdout` value in the `$writer->save()` method, check these rules for:

1) The directory returned by the `sys_get_temp_dir()` function. In Windows `sys_get_temp_dir()` by default returns the temporary directory of the current OS user. The value can be changed by `sys_temp_dir` php.ini directive.

or

2) The directory returned by the [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) php.ini directive. `$useUploadTempDirectory` has `false` value by default. To set it value to `true` add this line in your code before saving the file:

`\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);`

---

Here is the code that is responsible for selecting the save path:

From `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx::save` method ([source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/0c7df7721bbbdc62ed1e876a0fb332d62ad03ba7/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php#L179)):

```
// If $pFilename is php://output or php://stdout, make it a temporary file...
$originalFilename = $pFilename;
if (strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://output' || strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://stdout') {
    $pFilename = @tempnam(File::sysGetTempDir(), 'phpxltmp');
    if ($pFilename == '') {
        $pFilename = $originalFilename;
    }
}
```

From `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\SharedFile::sysGetTempDir` method ([source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/0c7df7721bbbdc62ed1e876a0fb332d62ad03ba7/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php#L110)):

```
/**
 * Get the systems temporary directory.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function sysGetTempDir()
{
    if (self::$useUploadTempDirectory) {
        //  use upload-directory when defined to allow 
        // running on environments having very restricted open_basedir configs
        if (ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') !== false) {
            if ($temp = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')) {
                if (file_exists($temp)) {
                    return realpath($temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return realpath(sys_get_temp_dir());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be in the office tomorrow and test it. Will give you feedback. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Other things came up in the office. So this is on ice at the moment. But I will come to it soon hopefully. Sorry.

Comment: Someone might find this useful: this error is also thrown when if the temporary file cannot be moved to its destination. The message can be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried everything and lost almost 3 hours with this issue. Finally "\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);" this works perferctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code is from an included file but I had a similar issue. I tried to use `__DIR__` constant and it worked, my code looks like this:

```
$filepath = __DIR__ . "/reports/${filename}_".date("Ymd_Gis").".xlsx";
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the tmp directory used by phpSpreadSheet and that was not writable by PHP process. I changed the tmp directory to upload tmp directory and now the issue is resolved. I solved the issue using

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);
```