# PHPSpreadsheet download xlsx in browser

Tags: php, browser, xlsx, phpoffice

I want download my generate Xlsx file on my browser but when I execute this code, the request is launched without error but nothing happens

```
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($pathfile).'');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


    File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objWorkBookExcel, 'Xlsx');

    $objWriter->save("php://output");
```

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2SbL.png)

When I use this :

```
$objWriter->save($pathfile);
```

My file is generated on my server

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [PHPspreedsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the evolution of PHPOffice!

Try that:

```
$objWriter = io_factory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');


header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=nameoffile.xlsx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

If you use PHPExcel:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
die();
```

Comment: [2020-06-09 15:12:02] default.WARNING: Exception 'ErrorException' with message 'ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory'

Comment: have you change my filename?

Comment: see here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470370/phpspreadsheet-permissions-ziparchiveclose-failure-to-create-temporary-f)

Comment: I add :   File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true); the error is gone, I have content but the file does not download

Comment: without that control?

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm here

```
  $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objWorkBookExcel, 'Xlsx');

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='nameoffile.xlsx'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    File::setUseUploadTempDirectory(true);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');      
    exit;
```

[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gacT.png)

but no downloaded file