# Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Could not find zip member

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet, php-7.4

I have installed the latest version of [this](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) library using Composer. I created a test file to test the library's functionality, but when I try to parse a file and make a data array out of it, I get this error;

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Could not find zip member zip:///home/klik/tmp/php4cfRJH#_rels/.rels in /home/klik/scripts/PhpSpreadsheet-master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php:159
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/klik/scripts/PhpSpreadsheet-master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php(392): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::assertFile('/home/klik/tmp/...', '_rels/.rels')
> #1 /home/klik/scripts/PhpSpreadsheet-master/test.php(37): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx->load('/home/klik/tmp/...')
> #2 {main}
> thrown in **/home/klik/scripts/PhpSpreadsheet-master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/File.php** on line **159**

This is my `test.php` file:

```html
<?php

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFile">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>';

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 
    $file_mimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
     
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $file_mimes)) {
     
        $arr_file = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = end($arr_file);
      
        if('csv' == $extension) {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
        } else {
            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        }
  
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
 
        print_r($sheetData);exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I am using the simplest `.xls` Excel file for processing.

[image: img]

---

php -v version used:

PHP 7.4.14 (cli) (built: Jan 30 2021 20:03:43) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

---

Comment: may be it's permission issue ! OR you can just check over here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476471/3340665

Comment: It is not related to permissions. i check permissions ... ini_get('open_basedir'); = /home/klik and "chmod -R 777 /home/klik/scripts/PhpSpreadsheet-master/"

Comment: @IvanSavin Have you solved this problem?

Comment: For me I just had a password on the excel file

Comment: I got this error and Google sent me here. In my case it was because I had the .xlsx file open in Microsoft Excel 365 while executing the script.

Answer (score 7):

```php
if('csv' == $extension) {     
  $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
} else if('xls' == $extension) {     
  $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
} else     
  $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
```

Comment: Please Add some description in this snippet !

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in my laravel application and i got the same errors.
It solved by specifying the full path of the file.
In my case: it is e.g., \Excel::import(new MatchingImport, 'full_path_of_the_file_here');
In your case, try to add full path on line: $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
`$spreadsheet = $reader->load('full_path_of_the_file_here');`

Answer (score 0):

You must use load static of function \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory instead PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).