# PhpSpreadsheet Fatal Error "Could not find zip member"

Tags: php, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Hi am using PhpSpreadsheet, and here is my code:

```
switch ($file_extension) {
      case 'xlsx':
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
        break;
      case 'xls':
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
        break;
      default:
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Csv();
        break;
  }
  $spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Now I am uploading excelsheet using Ajax, from two source -

1. From Local Device: `var fileName = $(this).find('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0]; //with tmp_name = C:\xampp\tmp\php742D.tmp`
2. From Google Drive: `var fileName = new File([res.body], doc.name, { type: doc.mimeType }) //with tmp_name = C:\xampp\tmp\php1F2A.tmp`

So, when my php code executing `$spreadsheet = $reader->load($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` this line giving fatal error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception: Could not find zip member
> zip://C:\xampp\tmp\php2854.tmp#_rels/.rels in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebapp\GET-OCR\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php:159
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebapp\GET-OCR\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx.php(393):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File::assertFile('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...',
> '_rels/.rels')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebapp\GET-OCR\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\BaseReader.php(166):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx->loadSpreadsheetFromFile('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...')
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebapp\GET-OCR\controller\ajax-req.php(81): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\BaseReader->load('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...')
> #3 {main}   thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\myWebapp\GET-OCR\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php**
> on line **159**

I checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/50476471/3340665 & [PhpSpreadsheet: Permissions | ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470370/) But no help.

Comment: This happened to me, the key here is to really know the filetype, I suggest to:

Comment: - open the file that you want to process first with a software like Excel
- if the file is actually opening, check the file permissions
- to get the type don't look the extension, look for the mimetype with a function like
$file->getClientMimeType(); here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types you can find the common types, in this case:
application/vnd.ms-excel for .xls
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet for .xlsx
text/csv for .csv

"Could not find zip member" means that the file can't be processed/read

Comment: For uncertain filetype, I always use following as [doc](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#creating-a-reader-and-loading-a-spreadsheet-file) suggested : `**$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);**` > `**$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);**` > `**$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);**`